# How can I move flexboxed sidemenu from the bottom of the screen to the top on mobile?

Tags: html, css, mobile, flexbox, sidebar

I cant quite seem to figure out how to move my sidebar element from below my main content to above it. I used flexbox on most of my webpage, and then put my maincontent in one, and my sidebar in the other. On large screen, the sidebar is on the right, as it should be, on mobile it drops down below the maincontent.

I have styled the sidebar so that is show up as small boxes in one row, but I would like it to go *above* my maincontent on mobile, not beneath it.
Is there any way to achieve this? I could really use some help figuring this out.

I put wrapper, main-content and sidebar on codepen so you can see:
https://codepen.io/Pinchofginger/pen/WddJQW?editors=1100

[image: image of the problem]

My code

HTML

```
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body class="body" id="index">
  <header class="mainheader">
    </header>

  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="main">
 <article class="top-boks">

<header>
<h1>Velkommen til vores hjemmeside</h1>
</header>

<footer>
   <p class="underrubrik">   Et trygt hjem for herreløse katte  </p>
</footer>
                            <img src="billeder/Katte/siam.png" class="mellemh" alt="Burmeser fodres af kvinde" />

<!-- 1 --------------------------------------------------------------------------->
  <div class=brodtekst >
    <p> Vi arbejder utrætteligt på at give hjemløse tamkatte tilfredsstillende levevilkår. </p></div><!-- End, brodtekst  -->
       </article>

</div> <!-- End, main-->

<div class="sidemenu">

  <aside class="sidebar1">
    <article>
<a href="megadoner.html"><button class="landingbutt" id="Mega" type="button"><i class="fa fa-paw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<h3> Denne måneds <div class="knaek">MegaDonerer!</div></h3></button></a>
    </article>
    </aside>

    <a href="frivillig.html" class="pleje"><aside class="sidebar2" class="pleje">
  <article>
  <h3>Plejefamilier og Frivillige søges</h3>
</article>
</aside></a>

<a href="mathilde.html">
<aside class="sidebar2">
 <article>
<h3>Ugens kat</h3> <img src="billeder/Katte/Mathilde.jpg" alt="Mathilde">
<h5>  Mathilde,</h5>
    <p>dejlig senior-kat med masser af charme</p>
</article></aside></a>

<a href="sailor.html">
<aside class="sidebar2">
  <article>
    <h3>Ugens kat</h3>
  <img src="billeder/ungkat/sailor.jpg" alt="Sailor" >
<h5>   Sailor, </h5>
   <p>livlig og kær energibombe</p>
</article>
</aside></a>

<a href="mrgrey.html">
<aside class="sidebar2">
    <article>
<h3>Ugens killing</h3>
    <img src="billeder/killinger/mr.grey.jpg" alt="Mr.Grey" >
     <h5>Mr.Grey,</h5>
     <p>en herlig lille gut med fuld fart på!</p>
    </article>
</aside></a>

<a href="donation.html">
<aside class="sidebar3" id="donation">
<article>
      <img src="billeder/doner4.png">
</article>
 </aside></a>

</div> <!-- End, Sidemenu -->
</div> <!-- End, wrapper-->

  <footer class="mainfooter">
    <div id="footerbrodtekst ">
      <h3> Sponsorer </h3>
      <p>
        <a href="http://www.hillspet.dk/" target="_blank">
            <img class="sponsor" src="billeder/Hillslogo.jpg" alt="Hills Logo"></a>
      </p>

      <h3>Følg os online</h3>
      <div id=socialbar>
        <a href="https://da-dk.facebook.com/S%C3%B8nderborg-Kattelaug-223954954290456/" target="_blank"><img src="billeder/facebookicon.png" alt="facebook icon"></a>
        <a href="http://youtube.com" target="_blank"><img src="billeder/youtubeicon.png" alt="youtube icon"></a>
        <a href="http://snapchat.com" target="_blank"><img src="billeder/snapchaticon.png" alt="snapchat icon"></a>
      </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS

```
.sidemenu { display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
    display:-moz-flex;
      -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-shrink: 0;
width:100%;
 flex-direction:row; 
  -ms-flex-direction:row; 
  height:100%;}


.sidebar1 {display:none;}
.sidemenu img { height:70px; width:100%; margin: 0 auto; }
.sidemenu p{display:none;}

.sidebar1, .sidebar2, .sidebar3 {
   border: 1px solid lightgrey; }

.sidebar1 {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.sidebar2 {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 1% 0 0 0;
      padding: 0 1% 1% 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


.sidebar3 {
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
      padding: 0 1% 10% 1%;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.body {
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Alt er centreret*/
  width: 99%;}

  .wrapper {display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
      display:-moz-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction:column;
height: 100%;}

.main {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display:-moz-flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  -ms-flex-direction:column;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/
  }

  .underrubrik {display: none;}

  .top-boks {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px;
        /* pæne runde hjørner*/
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    /* IE */
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
      padding: 3% 3% 3% 3%;
    }

.bund-boks {
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 1% 0 1% 0;
    padding: 3% 3% 3% 3%;
}


/*************       TABLE!          *************************************/
table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 1em;
  /*  font-style: bold !important;    does not work error*/
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: lightgrey;
}




/******************************************************************************/

/*                               FOOTER!                                      */

/******************************************************************************/

.mainfooter {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
    display:-moz-flex;
  /* Lækkert layout, alt på linje og ude i kanterne */
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  font-size: 14px;
  float: left;
  background-image: url("billeder/katte/soph.png");
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 5px;
  position: relative;
  color: white;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #444444;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #404040;
  border-radius: 5px;
  /* pæne runde hjørner*/


  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  /* IE */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flex order and media queries should do the trick, 
[see on codepen](https://codepen.io/Ellanski/pen/rppKyJ?editors=1100)

HTML

```
<body>
  <main></main>
  <aside></aside>
</body>
```

CSS

```
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

main {
  background: red;
  width: 90%;
}

aside {
  background: blue;
  width: 10%;
}

@media all and (max-width: 760px) {

  body {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

  aside, main {
    width:100%;
  }

  aside {
    order: -1;
  }
}
```